# Calling a jQuery function inside an Angular directives after changes to ng-bind-html have finished

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Should moving a global jquery function inside an Angular directives link function, cause the code to function the same?

I thought it would but unfortunately it does not seem to work exactly the same..

Its basically a lot of jquery code adding events to elements and setting up listeners. I've verified that jquery can access elements outside of the directive html.

I've got problems with the click listeners.

here is the code:

```
 template: "<ul ng-bind-html='menuHtml'></ul>",
        link: function (scope, element, attr, $compile) {

            //some custom logic perhaps
            scope.$watch(
                "menuHtml",
                function (newValue, oldValue) {

                    if (newValue === "") {
                        return;
                    }
                    setupUIonTheNewRenderedHtml((jQuery)); // I think this needs to wait..

                }
            );
```

the funny thing is that when I debug this code the html is actually rendered before the $watch is fired

Comment: This is a very general question, and the general answer is, it depends. Please provide some more details or code or a specific issue.

Comment: Also generally if your jQuery code changes data inside event listeners or anything outside the angular context, you will have to $apply your changes so that angular knows about it.

Comment: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: @NathanielJohnson not sure how that helps, jquery needs to know when angular updates the UI

Comment: I guess I am not really certain about what you are asking. Can you post a plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the JQuery stuff in a call to `$timeout`, since Angular won't render the DOM untill the `$digest` cycle you're currently in is finished.

```
$timeout(function() {
    setupUIonTheNewRenderedHtml((jQuery));
}, 0);
```

Comment: putting $timeout inside the directive results in it never being called

Comment: That's strange, we're doing that approach in several directives where we're using JQuery. Where is `setupUIonTheNewRenderedHtml` defined? It might not be in scope when the `$timeout` fires. Are there any errors on the console?

Comment: `setupUIonTheNewRenderedHtml` is just declared (non scoped) in the link function, no errors

Comment: Could have something to do with how you're passing values into the directive's scope, I got a similar case working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/nUm86mW1sUU3TrJfuAzT?p=preview

Comment: Maybe if you can reproduce your problem in a plnkr it would be easier to figure it out